# Setting Build Action on a view sql definition

Tags: visual-studio-2013, database-project, dacpac

When refactoring a database project, I usually set temporarily invalidated SQL files propertiy "Build Action" to "None" so it doesn't break the build.

[image]

With some of the views, I seem to be getting a completely different view of properties that refers to "WrappedObject":

[image]

What does this mean?

Comment: Aside from the bug Steven will help with I would say if your refactoring is normally so large that you need to exclude files you should do smaller refactors or trust more in your source control and delete things you aren't using :)

Comment: Um... yes, ok, thanks. I'll do that.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a bug to me. If you're able to produce a sample solution that reproduces the problem, then I'd suggest reporting the issue to Microsoft via Connect at https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/CreateFeedback.aspx using the category "Developer Tools (SSDT, BIDS, etc.)".